# access config server properties that are injected with EnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am injecting properties w/ `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, they are legacy properties that come from another properties xml file,
how do I access the properties list w/ a REST URL?

```
@Component
public class SpringCloudConfigRuntimeEnvironmentPostProcessor implements
    EnvironmentPostProcessor {

@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("com.xyz.jdbcUrl", "x.y.z");
MapPropertySource propertySource = new MapPropertySource("defaultProperties", map);
environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
```

and I added it to spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.xyz.configservice.config.SpringCloudConfigRuntimeEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

when I print the environment I do see them being loaded

in application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
```

I can't find the right syntax to get those properties I loaded, a couple of the many I tried:
http://x.x.x.x:8888/config-service/defaultProperties-default.properties
http://x.x.x.x:8888/defaultProperties-default.properties

Comment: Config server doesn't send properties from it's environment. You'll want to create an EnvironmentRepository.

Comment: awesome @spencergibb , that works great! Cheers!